# Experienced Hacker in our System

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I'm new to this but this is serious. When I run netstat command I get a list of IP addresses that I presume are suppose to be there. However, several of our accounts have been hacked. We know the person doing it and his IP address is listed at the very bottom of that netstat list when I first open it. After, I get a running list of IP addresses and the hacker's shows up still here and there.

What's going on and how do I keep him out?

Comment: If you know the person, why can't you just snitch on his face? I mean, read him a lesson so he will stop.

Comment: The most obvious suggestion would be a firewall, but the specific implementation of a firewall can vary depending on your network topology. Is the hacker internal or external? how are you certain that the IP address you believe is the hacker, actually is said hacker? what ports is the hacker coming in on? what devices do you have on the network between your ISP device (modem/router) and the computer being hacked?

Comment: We've had "discussions" with the hacker and the IP address is 2800 miles away right over his house. He runs a web service and has experience. We're handing this one over to my boss. If he sees this then there's no point. I thank you very much and will recommend your site to others. By the way from what we traced his IP seems as if it's coming from a virtual machine but I don't have the log with me to explain how far this was traced. This system uses Norton and I'll take a look at blocking incoming connections. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would assume the hacker, if experienced at least, is using a proxy service in order to mask his real IP. I'm not sure how you determined the IP is from a VM...IPs are logical, all layer 3, no way to tell the if that is a VM or not...

Answer (score 1):

If you know the IP address that the hacker is connecting from, then you could use [Windows Firewall](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/windows-firewall-from-start-to-finish) (or another firewall) to block incoming connections from that IP address.